# Why can my queue not be found in context lookup?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We have a service to send messages to an IBM MQ queue.

I'm trying to get this to work in Liberty, but when the service class is in postConstruct I get a NullPointerException looking up the queue by its JNDI name.

Here is the relevant portion of the server.xml configuration:

```
<resourceAdapter id="mqJms" location="/etc/liberty/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
<authData id="mqJms.auth" user="user" password="password"/>

<jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/queueConnectionFactory" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr4" containerAuthDataRef="mqJms.auth">
    <properties.mqJms transportType="CLIENT"
        hostName="server" port="1234"
        channel="CHANNEL"/>
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

<connectionManager id="ConMgr4"
    connectionTimeout="30s"
    maxPoolSize="50" minPoolSize="1"
    reapTime="60s" agedTimeout="0"/>

    <jmsQueue id="jms/outgoingRequestQueue" jndiName="jms/outgoingRequestQueue">
        <properties.mqJms queueName="QUEUEOUT"/>
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="earname/warname/JMSService" authDataRef="mqJms.auth">
        <properties.mqJms destinationRef="jms/outgoingRequestQueue" destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"/>
    </jmsActivationSpec>
```

This is the error I get:

```
J2CA8500E: An error occurred while attempting to configure a property queueName of configuration element com.ibm.ws.jca.adminObject.supertype[jms/incomingResponseQueue] on the class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.configure(BootstrapContextImpl.java:471)
```

Which makes me think that maybe there is something missing in the server.xml, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MQ resource adapter documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031680_.htm#q031680___q031680_3), the `queueName` attribute should actually be `baseQueueName`. Additionally, you might need to specify the `queueManager` on the connection factory or the `baseQueueManagerName` on the `jmsQueue` properties if the default qmgr value of an empty string isn't valid for your connection.

Comment: Most of the time it is better to leave `baseQueueManagerName` empty,  mq by default will resolve a locally defined queue on the `queueManager`.

Comment: Is `queueManager` always required or are there situations where it can be left off?

Comment: queueManager can be left `NULL` or all spaces or `*`, this is a special case that tells MQ to ignore the queue manager name of the queue manager you connect to and accept any.  If you specify a value other than those the QM name you connect to must match what you specify or you receive a queue manager name error.  If you were using a CCDT then there is another case where you specify a QMName proceeded by a `*`, MQ will look up the entrie(s) in the CCDT that match the name with out the `*` and connect to one of them and will NOT try to match the name, this is called a QMGroup.

Comment: The baseQueueName was the problem, thanks very much. Now I have a rollback error which I have to figure out, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: You'll probably want to open another question on that one if you can't figure it out. I think if this one is finished you can mark it accepted so people know it doesn't need attention.